# Cannot connect cups client with server

Tags: 16.04, server, printing

I have a print server running Ubuntu Server 16.04 with a HPLaserJet9050N network printer installed (with a ppd) And it prints ok.
In another machine I have an Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 and I'm trying to make it send jobs to the print server. I created the file /etc/cups/client.conf with the content:

```
ServerName printsrv.mydomain.ar:631
```

which is the correct address of the server.

But when I try to do something like lpstat -a I get:

```
lpstat: Error - añada '/version=1.1' al nombre del servidor.
```

Which is strange, because both server and client are running CUPS 2.1.3-4, so I shouldn't need to use that workaround for old CUPS servers. I do it anyway but I get the same result.

Just to try, I change the address in the client.conf file to another server (the one I'm trying to replace) with Debian Etch and CUPS 1.3.8 AND IT WORKS with the "/version=1.1" workaround:

```
Myusee@client-pc:/etc/cups$ lpstat -a
HPLaserJet9050N aceptando peticiones desde jue 18 may 2017 16:55:21 ART
```

All the computers are on the same subnet and the firewall is treating the old and the new server exactly the same way.

A `tcpdump` for port 631 on both client and server shows that the packets are being sent and recieved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this was your problem but this may help someone:

If you're getting the `lpstat: Error - add '/version=1.1' to the server name` error when you've added '/version=1.1`to the server URI in your`lpstat`command or in`/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`, make sure the server is up, running, and accessible! It threw the error for me until I realized the server was down.